# Measurability of piecewise constant function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, piecewise-continuity

If $(X, \mathbb A, m)$ is a measurable space and if we have a function $f: (X, \mathbb A) \to (\mathbb R, B(\mathbb R))$ which is measurable, non-negative and piecewise constant, why does - in this case - hold that $$\int f dm = \sum_{a \in f(X)} a \cdot m( \{ x \in X: f(x) = a \}) $$

Comment: Write it as a linear combination of indicator functions and then integrate. Also use the fact that simple functions have a canonial representations.

Answer (score 1):

If the image of $f$ is finite then the equation is clear since we can write $f$ as a simple function and use the definition of the integral. Otherwise, if the image of $f$ is countable, we can order the image set as $(y_1, y_2, \dotsc,)$ in increasing order (we want to avoid uncountable sums) and write $f$ as the limit of the increasing sequence of simple functions $\sum_{j=1}^k y_j I(f(x)=y_j)$ from which the desired result is clear by the MCT theorem.

Comment: Wow thank you, that makes sense! What can one say about measurability in general of such piecewise constant functions?